# How to make a customizable button from user input?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and am working on a project that allows users to customize the buttons by holding them down and a popup window will show to allow users to edit it. Is there any widget or method to achieve the result below?

This is how it looks initially, after pressing 'a' it shows 'a':

[image]

I want it to be changeable based on user input and when pressed, it shows a value instead of '*':

[image]

I hardcoded the results to give a better understanding which is obviously not ideal and currently using list and gird view to make the buttons. Thank you in advance!

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';
import 'button.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var userQuestion = '';
  var userAns = '';

  final List<String> buttons1 = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D',
    'E',
    'F',
    'G',
    'H',
    'I',
    'J',
    'K',
    'L',
    'M',
    'N',
    'O',
    'P',
    'Q',
    'R',
    'S',
    'T'
  ];
  final List<String> buttons2 = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
    'd',
    'e',
    'f',
    'g',
    'h',
    'i',
    'j',
    'k',
    'l',
    'm',
    'n',
    'o',
    'p',
    'q',
    'r',
    's',
    't'
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              //Input and Output Screen
              flex: 10,
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Text(
                          userQuestion,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        )),
                    Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: Text(
                          userAns,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              )),
          //Page Indicator
          Expanded(
              child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [],
          )),
          Expanded(
            flex: 20,
            child: PageView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                      itemCount: buttons2.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 4),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return CustomButton(
                            buttonTapped: () {
                              setState(() {
                                userQuestion += buttons2[index];
                              });
                            },
                            color: Colors.white,
                            textColor: Colors.black,
                            text: buttons2[index],
                          );
                      }),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                      itemCount: buttons1.length,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 4),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return CustomButton(
                          buttonTapped: () {
                            setState(() {
                              userQuestion += buttons1[index];
                            });
                          },
                          color: Colors.black,
                          textColor: Colors.orange,
                          text: buttons1[index],
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to change the text inside of button by the value is written in text field?

Comment: Please provide your current code so that we can help you out

Comment: @AliHassan I want to let users decide what the text inside should be along with the value the text associates with. For example, if a users want '$' to be 54: the text inside the button should show $ and when they press it 54 should show in the tex field.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one, you need to make button widget seperatedly and give onTap constructor and loop it in the mainscreen to input the button value into `userAns`

MAIN SCREEN

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  var userAns = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Text(userAns),
        Column(
          children: ['A', 'B', 'C']
              .map(
                (e) => TestButton(
                  buttonText: e,
                  onTap: (buttonText) {
                    setState(() {
                      userAns += buttonText;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

BUTTON WIDGET

```
    class TestButton extends StatelessWidget {
  TestButton({Key? key, required this.buttonText, required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);
  final String buttonText;
  final Function onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        onTap(buttonText);
      },
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```